# Lilypond: how to engrave a break between choruses and output a single MIDI file?

Tags: lilypond, midi

I'm studying melodic structures in jazz solos, and am using Lilypond to annotate characteristics such as chord tone, non-chord tones, and enclosures.   I've written a Python script to automate the analysis and to generate the Lilypond file.

Currently, for each solo chorus, I embed the melody into a separate score (as show below).  This creates a nice break between choruses in the engraved output, but the midi output is split into several files, one for each chorus/score. Is there a way to output a single midi file containing all of the choruses?  Perhaps there is a better way to combine the choruses into a single score, but that maintains the breaks in a way similar to the output from the code shown below?

I suspect the answer is to use something like `\bookpart` and `\book`, but I don't want a page break between choruses... that would introduce too much vertical space.

**"West Coast Blues"**
**Wes Montgomery**

```
\include "swing.ly"
\version "2.24.1"\language "english"
\header { title = "West Coast Blues Solos"
 composer = "Wes Montgomery"
 tagline = "Transcription by C. Bunks" }

chord_progression = \chords { \set chordChanges = ##t 
 bf2.:7\pppp bf2.:7 af2.:7 af2.:7 bf2.:7 bf2.:7 b2.:m7 e2.:7 ef2.:7 ef2.:7 ef2.:m7 af2.:7 d2.:m7 g2.:7 cs2.:m7 fs2.:7 c2.:m7 c2.:m7 c2.:m7 f2.:7 bf2.:6 df2.:7 gf2.:6 f2.:7 }

melody = \fixed c'
{\clef treble\numericTimeSignature \time 3/4 \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  d'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'4  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  df8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  bf,8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c4  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  f''4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f''8  }   \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  f''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e''4  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'4  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  b8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gs8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef''16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e''16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef''16  }   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs''8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'16  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  d'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  b8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = #black  d'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  }   \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  d''8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  f''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  a8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'8  }   \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'2  }   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r2  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  } }

\score { 
\tripletFeel 8 
<< 
\new ChordNames { \chord_progression } 
\new Staff  \with { instrumentName = "Chorus 1" } 
 { \melody }
 >> 
\layout { }
\midi { \tempo 4 = 192 }
}

melody = \fixed c'
{\clef treble\numericTimeSignature \time 3/4 \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8 gf'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8 ef'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8 df'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  a16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8 bf16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8 af'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8 f'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8 ef'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8 df'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs''16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8 d''16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b'8 b'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gs'16  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  a'8 a'16  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  g'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gs'8 gs'16  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf4  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'4 af'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'4  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  e'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \stopStaffHighlight   \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  a8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gs4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c'4  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  f'8  }   \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b,4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b8}

\score { 
\tripletFeel 8 
<< 
\new ChordNames { \chord_progression } 
\new Staff  \with { instrumentName = "Chorus 2" } 
 { \melody }
 >> 
\layout { }
\midi { \tempo 4 = 192 }
}

melody = \fixed c'
{\clef treble\numericTimeSignature \time 3/4 \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af8  }   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  }   \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  }   \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df''8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  f''4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  e'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = #black  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  a'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  cs''8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  e''8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  d''4  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''4  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''4  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ff''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  }   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'4  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'4  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  df''8  }   \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  e''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = #black  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'16  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  b'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  ef''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df''8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d'4}

\score { 
\tripletFeel 8 
<< 
\new ChordNames { \chord_progression } 
\new Staff  \with { instrumentName = "Chorus 3" } 
 { \melody }
 >> 
\layout { }
\midi { \tempo 4 = 192 }
}

melody = \fixed c'
{\clef treble\numericTimeSignature \time 3/4 \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  }   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c'4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g'4  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  bf'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \stopStaffHighlight   \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  bf'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  fs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  fs8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  a16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gs8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  g''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  c''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  a'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs'4  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  gs8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  gs8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  b8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  cs'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  fs8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  e8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  f'8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  d'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  }   \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  d''8  \staffHighlight "silver" \override NoteHead.color = dodgerblue  f''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef''8  \stopStaffHighlight   \override NoteHead.color = orangered  g'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  cs''8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  d''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  e'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'16  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \tuplet 3/2 {   \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'16  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'16  \override NoteHead.color = #black  df'16  }   \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  d'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'4 f'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  r8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  b'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  df''8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  bf'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  f'8  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  ef'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'8  \override NoteHead.color = #black  gf'4  \override NoteHead.color = #black  af'4  \override NoteHead.color = orangered  f'4}

\score { 
\tripletFeel 8 
<< 
\new ChordNames { \chord_progression } 
\new Staff  \with { instrumentName = "Chorus 4" } 
 { \melody }
 >> 
\layout { }
\midi { \tempo 4 = 192 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, if we reduce what you are doing to the essentials: Your are currently doing something like this:

```
%%% Version A

\new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Chorus 1"
} { c1 c c c }

\new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Chorus 2"
} { c1 c c c }

\new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Chorus 3"
} { c1 c c c }
```

and want to get contiguous MIDI output. One way to do this would be to use a single score and use e.g. Section labels like this:

```
%%% Version B

{
  \sectionLabel "Chorus 1"
  c1 c c c\break
  
  \sectionLabel "Chorus 2"
  c1 c c c\break
  
  \sectionLabel "Chorus 2"
  c1 c c c\break
}
```

(using overrides to short instrument name and using the pseudoindent snippet https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=1098 you could even get the same optical behaviour as multiple scores give). The other option would be to create separate scores for the graphics, but a single score for MIDI:

```
%%% Version C

chorusA = { c1 c c c }
chorusB = { c1 c c c }
chorusC = { c1 c c c }

\new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Chorus 1"
} \chorusA

\new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Chorus 2"
} \chorusB

\new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Chorus 3"
} \chorusC

\score {
  { \chorusA \chorusB \chorusC }
  \midi { }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the 2nd option (Version C), and it worked well.  I did have to experiment a bit with the chord progression to get it to work.  I finally worked out that it should be replicated the same number of times as the number of choruses.